# How to evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{12n+1} $?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

First of all, I am going to convert this series into a definite integral.
For $|x|<1,$ we have
$\displaystyle \quad \frac{1}{1+x^{12}}=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-x^{12}\right)^{n}=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} x^{12 n} \tag*{} $
Integrating both sides from $x=0$ to $1$, we can relate the target series and the definite integral.
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac{d x}{1+x^{12}} =\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1}(-1)^{n} x^{12 n} d x 
\displaystyle =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[(-1)^{n} \frac{x^{12 n+1}}{12n+1}\right]_{0}^{1} \displaystyle =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{12 n+1}$$

By my [post](https://artisticmathematics.quora.com/How-do-I-integrate-1-1-x-12-2?ch=17&oid=260885548&share=edd093ae&srid=CCOmo&target_type=answer),

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{12 n+1}$
$\displaystyle \\ \displaystyle  =\frac{1}{24 \sqrt{2}}\left[2 \ln \left(\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2-\sqrt{2}}\right)+(1+\sqrt{3}) \ln \left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+1}{2 \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}-1}\right)\right.\\$
$\displaystyle \qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad \left.+(\sqrt{3}-1) \ln \left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}+1}\right)+2(1+\sqrt{3}) \pi\right] \\$

(checked by [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/i=%E2%88%AB_0%5E1%20dx%2F%281%2Bx%5E%2812%29%29))

***My question***

How to generalize the result for
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k n+1}$$

where $n\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: Use [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7.E7) with $z=1/n$.

Comment: @Gary, thank you for your link, by which I get immediately  $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{n k+1}=\frac{1}{2 n}\left[\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2 n}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{2 n}\right)\right]$, but I don’t know how to simplify it.

Comment: @Lai You can use [this result](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.4.E19).

Comment: Gauss' digamma theorem, also seen at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssDigammaTheorem.html  [It is, indeed, due to Gauss, even though reading that page may lead you to assume it is due to Knuth.]

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the original integral, using the same technique yields
$\displaystyle \quad \frac{1}{1+x^{n}}=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-x^{n}\right)^{k}=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k} x^{nk} ,\tag*{}
$
we have
Integrating both sides from $x=0$ to $1$, we can relate the target series and the definite integral.
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac{d x}{1+x^{n}} =\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1}(-1)^{k} x^{nk} d x 
\displaystyle =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[(-1)^{k} \frac{x^{nk+1}}{nk+1}\right]_{0}^{1} \displaystyle =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{nk+1}$$
By the Dr Brian Sittinger’s [post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-value-of-int_0-1-frac-1-1-x-n-dx/answer/Brian-Sittinger?ch=17&oid=194503947&share=ad8c47ec&srid=CCOmo&target_type=answer),

A. when $n=2m$ is even, we obtain the series$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k n+1}\\=\boxed{\frac{1}{2 m} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\left[\frac{(2 k+1) \pi}{2 m} \sin \left(\frac{(2 k+1) \pi}{2 m}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{(2 k+1) \pi}{2 m}\right) \ln \left(2-2 \cos \left(\frac{(2 k+1) \pi}{2 m}\right)\right)\right]}
$$
B. when $n=2m+1$ is odd, we obtain the series$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k n+1}\\ =\boxed{\frac{\ln 2}{2 m+1}+\frac{1}{2 m+1} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\left[\frac{(2 k+1) \pi}{2 m+1} \sin \left(\frac{(2 k+1) \pi}{2 m+1}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{(2 k+1) \pi}{2 m+1}\right) \ln \left(2-2 \cos \left(\frac{(2 k+1) \pi}{2 m+1}\right)\right)\\+2 \sin \left(\frac{(2 k+1) \pi}{2 m+1}\right) \cdot \arctan \left(\cot \left(\frac{(2 k+1) \pi}{2 m+1}\right)\right)\right]}
$$